# Draw grid lines at multiples of k

Tags: plotting, grid-layouts

Here is a beginner's question: when creating plots with mathematica, I want the grid lines to be at multiples of a constant value. E.g. in the following plot, the vertical grid lines are at multiple of 2 $\pi$.
[image]

This is the corresponding Mathematica code:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, n*2*π}, 
  GridLines -> {2*π*# & /@ Range[n], None}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Dashed], {n, 1, 50, 1}]
```

Since equidistant grid lines are very common, I wonder if there is an easier way than to use such complicated expressions like `2*π*# & /@ Range[n]` to generate equidistant grid lines. Does Mathematica provide anything simpler?

Comment: You could also use `Array[2 \[Pi] #, n]`.

Comment: @Pickett you forgot a `&`, but yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see case #4 in [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica/7925#7925).  You don't need `Function` and `Map` in `2*π*# & /@ Range[n]` -- instead use the "listability" of `Times` and write:  `2 π Range[n]`.  Also, while it doesn't simplify this application, in many cases it is easier to give the specification for `GridLines` as a function, e.g.:

```
 GridLines -> {2 π Range[#2] &, None}
```

where the arguments of the function are automatically drawn from the [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotRange.html) of the graphic.

Answer (score 4):

Since multiplication is Listable, you can simply use 2 Pi Range[n]:

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 n Pi}, 
  GridLines -> {2 Pi Range[n], None}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Dashed]
,
  {n, 1, 50, 1}
]
```

which looks clearer

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to get equally spaced gridlines based on a parameter:

```
grids[n_][min_, max_] := n Range @@ ({Floor@First@#, Ceiling@Last@#} &@Quotient[#, n] &@{min, max})

Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0,  n },
  GridLines -> grids[Pi],
  GridLinesStyle -> Dashed],
  {n, 1, 50}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]